# Getting a slice of integers from a string integer in Go?

Tags: string, go, int, slice

I want to convert a string representing and integer into a slice containing each integer that made up the initial string.

[Playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/KgQrbesy5rT)

I've tried using the `Atoi()` function in `strconv`, it it gives *"cannot use toCheck[i] (type byte) as type string in argument to strconv.Atoi"*. I've also tried int() conversion, but it's giving me what I believe are ASCII values - I know that I can just subtract 48, but that seems a little hacky.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

toCheck := "987654321"

    var toSum []int
    for i := len(toCheck) - 2; i >= 0; i = i-2 {
        toSum = append(toSum, int(toCheck[i]))
    }

    fmt.Println(toSum)

    // expected 2 4 6 8
    // actual 50 52 54 56
}
```

Expected output: 2 4 6 
Actual: 50 52 54 56

Answer (score 2):

> but it's giving me what I believe are ASCII values - I know that I can just subtract 48, but that seems a little hacky.

It's not hacky. You have a byte representing an ascii digit and you want to get its value as an integer from 0-9. That's how you do it. That's also how converting a string to an integer works in general. You convert each individual byte to a number using this method.

The UTF-8 representation for '0' is not going to change anytime soon. Of course, instead of subtracting `48` you can subtract `'0'`.

To make it more general purpose, maybe you should also return a boolean indicating whether the byte can be converted or not.

```
func ByteToInt(c byte) (int, bool) {
    if c >= '0' && c <= '9' {
        return int(c - '0'), true
    } else {
        return 0, false
    }
}
```

You can use this in your code sample and it would return your expected result:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func ByteToInt(c byte) (int, bool) {
    if c >= '0' && c <='9' {
        return int(c - '0'), true
    } else {
        return 0, false
    }
}

func main() {

toCheck := "987654321"

    var toSum []int
    for i := len(toCheck) - 2; i >= 0; i = i-2 {
        var digit, _ = ByteToInt(toCheck[i])
        toSum = append(toSum, digit)
    }

    fmt.Println(toSum)

}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/MRqtgY0ugZY

The output is what you expect: `[2 4 6 8]`

Answer (score 1):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    toCheck := "987654321"
    fmt.Println(toCheck)
    toSum := make([]int, 0, len(toCheck)/2)
    for i := len(toCheck) - 2; i >= 0; i -= 2 {
        c := toCheck[i]
        if c >= '0' && c <= '9' {
            toSum = append(toSum, int(c-'0'))
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(len(toSum), cap(toSum), toSum)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/wtIgqEKj-Bk

Output:

```
987654321
4 4 [2 4 6 8]
```

---

This is Go. Code should be reasonably efficient. For example,

```
$ go test sum_test.go -bench=. -benchmem
BenchmarkPeterSO-8         50000000     24.5 ns/op    32 B/op    1 allocs/op
BenchmarkTom-8             20000000     77.6 ns/op    56 B/op    3 allocs/op
BenchmarkUser10753492-8    20000000     79.0 ns/op    56 B/op    3 allocs/op
BenchmarkGrissom-8         20000000    108 ns/op      56 B/op    3 allocs/op
$
```

`sum_test.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "strconv"
    "testing"
)

// https://play.golang.org/p/wtIgqEKj-Bk
func BenchmarkPeterSO(b *testing.B) {
    toCheck := "987654321"
    for N := 0; N < b.N; N++ {
        toSum := make([]int, 0, len(toCheck)/2)
        for i := len(toCheck) - 2; i >= 0; i -= 2 {
            c := toCheck[i]
            if c >= '0' && c <= '9' {
                toSum = append(toSum, int(c-'0'))
            }
        }
    }
}

// https://play.golang.org/p/KgQrbesy5rT
func BenchmarkTom(b *testing.B) {
    toCheck := "987654321"
    for N := 0; N < b.N; N++ {
        var toSum []int
        for i := len(toCheck) - 2; i >= 0; i = i - 2 {
            toSum = append(toSum, int(toCheck[i]))
        }
    }
}

func ByteToInt(c byte) (int, bool) {
    if c >= '0' && c <= '9' {
        return int(c - '0'), true
    } else {
        return 0, false
    }
}

// https://play.golang.org/p/MRqtgY0ugZY
func BenchmarkUser10753492(b *testing.B) {
    toCheck := "987654321"
    for N := 0; N < b.N; N++ {
        var toSum []int
        for i := len(toCheck) - 2; i >= 0; i = i - 2 {
            var digit, _ = ByteToInt(toCheck[i])
            toSum = append(toSum, digit)
        }
    }
}

// https://play.golang.org/p/kNbQVn8GJ9R
func BenchmarkGrissom(b *testing.B) {
    toCheck := "987654321"
    for N := 0; N < b.N; N++ {
        var toSum []int
        for i := len(toCheck) - 2; i >= 0; i = i - 2 {
            v, _ := strconv.Atoi(string(toCheck[i]))
            toSum = append(toSum, v)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `strconv` package to do the conversion

```
  for i := len(toCheck) - 2; i >= 0; i = i-2 {
        v,_ := strconv.Atoi(string(toCheck[i]))
        toSum = append(toSum, v)
    }
```

strconv.Atoi is shortcut for strconv.ParseInt(s,10,0).

finish in your playground
https://play.golang.org/p/kNbQVn8GJ9R